# How to apply Filter and and copy filter results to another sheet using C# and Excel Interop

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, interop, spreadsheet

I want to apply a filter to a excel sheet and copy the resulting rows to another sheet and save it using C# (interop).

I tried like this:

`range.AutoFilter(1, "1", ..,..,..);`

`filteredRange = range.specialcells(..celltypeVisible, ..);`

In this code, `filteredRange` size is always 1 row.

Comment: @vyshkh99, is any update? Please check if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to copy filter results to another sheet.

```
        string path = "D:\\Test.xlsx";
        Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
        app.CutCopyMode = Excel.XlCutCopyMode.xlCut;
        Excel.Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(path);
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[1];
        Excel.Worksheet newWorksheet= (Excel.Worksheet)app.Worksheets.Add();
        Excel.Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;
        worksheet.AutoFilterMode = false;
        range.AutoFilter(1, "Test2");
        worksheet.AutoFilter.Range.Copy();
        newWorksheet.AutoFilterMode = false;
        newWorksheet.Paste();
        workbook.Save();
        workbook.Close();
```

Sheet1:

[image]

Sheet2:

[image]